# Visual Studio 2010 - C# Updater

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

a couple of weeks ago I made a small application which comes with the Installer, done with V.S.2010 tool. Now I need to upgrade the application, but I'd to deploy it as an update of the previous one.

How should I do? Is there some online doc that I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you used **OneClick** technology for your Installer, **Visual Studio does not support** Install "Updates".

You will need to resend the entire Setup first, ask the user to remove the old one first (you can force this in the Setup project)

If you install the new updatedApp without forcing removing and without installing, it will overwrite all files that the new updateApp has.